# Combining pd.read_csv and pd.read_excel

Tags: python, pandas, python-re

I've been assigned a task which involves merging the `pd.read_csv()` and the `pd.read_excel()` functions together into one function called `ingest()`. I've been trying to use regular expressions so that if the file contains a ".csv" it will execute the `read_csv()` function or else it will read it as an excel file.

This is my code so far

```
    rexf = re.compile((r'.csv'))
    mo = rexf.search(dataframe)
    if mo == True:
        df = pd.read_csv(dataframe)
    else:
        df = pd.read_excel(dataframe)
    return df
```

I then call this function with a file called "Smoking.csv". This file works when I use the `pd.read_csv()` command but here it goes berserk and gives me this error

`xlrd.biffh.XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found`

Does anyone know why this may be, and how I can get the function to behave as intended? Thanks.

Comment: Check what `mo` is. It is either a `re.Match` object, or `None`, neither of those will ever be `== True`, so you will never use `pd.read_csv` ad it will always use `pd.read_excel`

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using regex for this. It will work, but if you're dealing with paths you should use a tool for handling paths - like pathlib:

```
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd


def ingest(filename):
    path = Path(filename)
    if path.suffix == ".csv":
        df = pd.read_csv(dataframe)
    else:
        df = pd.read_excel(dataframe)
    return df
```

The reason your regex doesn't work is because of the `if` statement. A match object does not equal True. You could instead do `if mo:` which would work. But again... pathlib!

Answer (score 1):

A function like this one should do it:

```
def ingest(file_name):
   if file_name.endswith('.csv'):
      df = pd.read_csv(file_name)
   else:
      df = pd.read_excel(file_name)
   return df
```

Comment: Thank you, that's a real save